# How do I use Kdevelop to debug embedded code?

Tags: gdb, xilinx, gdbserver, kdevelop

I have a project for Xilinx Zynq (Cortex A9). I want to be able to step-by-step debug the application in KDevelop.  I know that xilinx has XSCT but I don't understand how can I get KDevelop to work in step-by-step code debugging mode for my processor?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I can advise you to learn how to do this from the terminal first and deal with the work of gdb-server. And also get a suitable make/cmake file.